# How to convert byte order in unix commands

Tags: oracle, unix, sql-loader, endianness

I couldn't find any relative command to convert the file to little endian. As i receive the data file from system and I use the `sqlldr` to load the data into oracle table. In control file the *byte ordering* has been made like below

```
BYTEORDER LITTLE ENDIAN
BYTEORDERMARK NOCHECK
```

Which means the file will be converted to little endian format (system format), here the `sqlldr` loads the data into table. somehow i try to read the data from file directly through `vi` though its unicode format is different hence i couldn't read the same. I tried searching the commands to convert the normal file and i had came over `iconv` commads and i used like below

```
iconv -c -t UTF-8LE filename.dat > output.txt
```

but it doesnot give output as expected.

Comment: What is the input charset for your file? UTF16BE?

Comment: @ibre5041 The character set seems to be `application/octet-stream; charset=binary` by issue of `file -i` command

Comment: I'm not sure whether you have problems with endianity. In case of text files, this usually applies onto to UTF16 inputs. ASCII and UTF8 do not have problems with endianity. You should find out which is the charset of your files.